# Module 'io' has no attribute '_WindowsConsoleIO'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, unit-testing, installation

I'm trying to get pytest to run on a Windows PC. It's working fine on one machine but another is giving an error even when I just try `pytest.exe --version`. The machine that works is a Windows 10 business version but this one is a Windows 10 Home version (x64). It has multiple versions of Python installed but I've tried running this under both 3.6 and 3.6-32 with no difference in outcome.

It was installed via: `py -3.6 -m pip install -U pytest`

The output from running `pytest.exe --version` is:

```
PS C:\tests\unit> pytest.exe --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\pyuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\python36\Scripts\pytest.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 63, in main
    config = _prepareconfig(args, plugins)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 207, in _prepareconfig
    pluginmanager=pluginmanager, args=args
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 289, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 203, in _multicall
    gen.send(outcome)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\helpconfig.py", line 94, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    config = outcome.get_result()
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 187, in _multicall
    res = hook_impl.function(*args)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 687, in pytest_cmdline_parse
    self.parse(args)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 895, in parse
    self._preparse(args, addopts=addopts)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\config\__init__.py", line 851, in _preparse
    early_config=self, args=args, parser=self._parser
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py", line 289, in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 87, in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py", line 81, in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 208, in _multicall
    return outcome.get_result()
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 80, in get_result
    raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\pluggy\callers.py", line 182, in _multicall
    next(gen)  # first yield
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 50, in pytest_load_initial_conftests
    _py36_windowsconsoleio_workaround(sys.stdout)
  File "c:\users\pyuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\_pytest\capture.py", line 820, in _py36_windowsconsoleio_workaround
    if not isinstance(raw_stdout, io._WindowsConsoleIO):
AttributeError: module 'io' has no attribute '_WindowsConsoleIO'
```

I can't find any references to this issue online and I have no idea why the `io` module would be missing the `_WindowsConsoleIO` attribute.

Comment: Do you have `PYTHONPATH` defined? Or does "C:\tests\unit\io.py" or "C:\tests\unit\io" exist?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` isn't defined, should it be? The unit test location doesn't contain either "io.py" nor an "io" subdir.

Comment: Run `py -3.6 -c "import io; print(io.__file__); print(hasattr(io, '_WindowsConsoleIO'))"`. What's the output?

Comment: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64\lib\io.py
True`

Comment: Something is mixed up here. You have a regular per-user installation in "C:\Users\pyuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36" and also a Visual Studio install in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python36_64". The latter is apparently the version selected by `py -3.6`. From the command line, run `where pytest.exe`.